# best way to implement manual stage

Tags: jenkins-workflow

I see many examples of waiting for input to implement a manual "promotion" stage.

This leaves the impression of many jobs running (it is possible in our pipeline to promote any of the last builds to a major release).

Is there a better way to achieve this, or, are there plans to have a real manual step that dosn't leave Jenkins looking like its running loads of jobs

Comment: Have you found a response to this yet? I'm just getting into workflow/pipeline and am curious about it. It seems to appear that the job is running for hours/days...

Comment: not yet, I think I may try and implement some workaround by re-running the job with different parameters set

Comment: @CollinPeters i've started work on a "promote-rebuild" plugin. It adds a few things you can use like getting the change logs, adding a "promote" badge to your job and an ability to rebuild a job and know that this is for promoting a release. Source is here https://github.com/bbc/rebuild-plugin/tree/workflow-promote-plugin and an example trivial pipeline is here https://github.com/rossbeazley/pipelinetest/blob/master/Jenkinsfile

Lots of tidy up to do, but there are integration tests and it appears to mostly work.